# Substantif désignant le caractère touffu de quelque chose

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot, substantivation

Je m'y prends peut-être mal dans mes recherches, mais auriez-vous en tête le substantif qui désigne le caractère touffu de quelque-chose ? 
Par analogie :

- le caractère *simple* d'une démarche ⇒ la *simplicité* d'une
  démarche
- le caractère *touffu* d'un arbre ⇒ ?

Comment: En tout cas il ne s'agit pas de la *touffeur* :)

Answer (score 4):

Si un arbre est considéré *touffu* car il est épais et dense, peut-être on pourrait parler de sa  **densité**  et/ou son  **épaisseur**, mais je ne vois pas un mot unique qui capte les deux idées.

Comment: c'est vrai que lorsqu'on cherche les synonymes de l'adjectif *touffu*, on tombe sur épais et sur dense, en tête de liste mais cela reste léger. :(

Comment: Il y a toujours "l'arborescence" pour dire un peu pres "comme un arbre," mais malheureusement pour votre recherche, tous les arbres ne sont pas "touffu"! (sans parler du fait que "l'arborescense d'un arbre" ne dit pas grand-chose et sonne un peu redondant!)

Answer (score 1):

On pourrait employer **[Complexité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Complexit%C3%A9)** ou **[Exubérance](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exub%C3%A9rance)**